# CSS - Make SPAN extend to end of its container / fill empty space?

Tags: css, css-float, width, html

I have the following HTML layout for a website (powered by Network Solutions nsCommerceSpace) I am designing a theme for:

```
<div id="ctl00_breadcrumb" class="breadcrumb">
   <span id="ctl00_breadcrumbContent">
      <span><a href="/">[Name of Webstore]</a></span>
      <span>&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;</span>
      <span><a href="/page.aspx">Page</a></span>
      <span>&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;</span>
      <span>Here is a very long title of a product that is causing me much frustration because it jumps out of place.</span>
   </span>
</div>
```

The span tags with `<span>&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;</span>` in them are automatically generated to separate each item.

Here is a Fiddle of my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/5fvmJ/

Is there a way I can make the last SPAN tag fill the empty space, and just end when it hits the right side? I would just use `overflow: hidden;` to hide the extra text.

Any ideas? I know having all SPAN's makes this tough, but it's built-in functionality of the site that I cannot change.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think I found a pure CSS solution. You only missed two things:

- You have to use only `display: inline-block` in the `<span>` tags without `float: left`, because floating is actually contradictory with inline-block elements.
- You have to use `white-space: nowrap` in the parent `<div>`.

This way you don't need to specify a width for anything. :)

#### JSFiddle demo

http://jsfiddle.net/yz9TK/

#### CSS

(I cleaned it up a little bit)

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

body {
    background: #212121;
    color: #FFF;
}

#ctl00_breadcrumb {
    height: 45px;
    width: 960px;
    background-color: #707070;
    line-height: 45px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #585858;
    text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow:  0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
    box-shadow:  0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#ctl00_breadcrumbContent span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    line-height: 45px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#ctl00_breadcrumbContent span a { 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 45px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#ctl00_breadcrumbContent span:nth-child(even) {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -22px -4px -16px -4px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#ctl00_breadcrumbContent span:nth-child(1) { 
    border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
    background-color: #404040;
}

#ctl00_breadcrumbContent span:nth-child(2) {
    border-top: 22px solid #505050;
    border-bottom: 23px solid #505050;
    border-left: 15px solid #404040;
}

#ctl00_breadcrumbContent span:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: #505050;
}

#ctl00_breadcrumbContent span:nth-child(4) { 
    border-top: 22px solid #606060;
    border-bottom: 23px solid #606060;
    border-left: 15px solid #505050;
}

#ctl00_breadcrumbContent span:nth-child(5) {
    background-color: #606060;
}

#ctl00_breadcrumbContent span:nth-child(6) { 
    border-top: 22px solid #707070;
    border-bottom: 23px solid #707070;
    border-left: 15px solid #606060;
}

#ctl00_breadcrumbContent span:nth-child(7) { 
    background-color: #707070;
}

#ctl00_breadcrumbContent span:nth-last-child(1) {
    background-color: #707070;
}

#ctl00_breadcrumbContent span:nth-last-child(2) {
    border-top: 22px solid #707070;
    border-bottom: 23px solid #707070;
}
```

Comment: Amazing, good sir. Exactly what I was looking for. Props to you. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 8):

This span class did the trick for me...

```
span.empty_fill {
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Essentially used like this...

```
<div class='banner'><a href='/'><span class='empty_fill' /></a></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two different kind of answers, both not great:

1. http://jsfiddle.net/5fvmJ/14/: Set a `max-width` for the last span, to make sure that the background doesn't jump. You should then make sure that the text doesn't fall out.
2. Without any width changing, get the text dimensions, and only display the substring with `...` appended, which stays inside the bar: http://jsfiddle.net/5fvmJ/19/. You should do that dynamically. ( [Calculate text width with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript))

Comment: 1) That could work, but the width will always be different because the 'Page' title is different depending on the category you are looking at.

Comment: 2) Not sure if that can be done with JavaScript or jQuery? Server cannot take any server-side code... only client-side.

Comment: See the link in the edit at 2., and for 1: you are not setting a width, but a max-width. If the text is smaller than the width, it will just fit normally.

Comment: Right, but if I have a category called "Category' the width would be larger than if it were "Very Long Category". Now the text would jump again. SO I would have to make the max-width be the max-width of that space when the category is at its largest, but then if I have a short category title, the page title would be trimmed a lot, and would have a lot of wasted free space. I hope you understand what I'm trying to explain.

Comment: Aah! Yes, I get it now, you want to append more items behind the long item. Again, I think the second option is best: determine the width of the text, if it is too long make it shorter and append `...`.

Comment: See, I did set that up, but again I have the same issue: I don't know what the number of max characters I can have is, since it depends on the length of the previous items.... Maybe if I can calculate the total width of the previous items using jQuery and .css('width')?

Comment: I cannot give a lot more tips than what I have already given, you have to start experimenting a bit I think. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Try styling the span with `display:block` EX:

`<span style="display:block"> Here is a... </span>`

Comment: Doesn't make any change when used in conjunction with overflow:hidden ?  The purpose of display:block is to force the span to act more like a div

Comment: This isn't a total solution, but it may work as a fix?  Adding display:block allows you to set a fixed width for the span... still not sure why overflow doesn't work in your example on Fiddle

Comment: Oh, well with a width specified it works, but that's my problem... I don't have a value I can set it to, since it always needs to be different since the titles of the pages/categories are of different lengths.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify the width.
Simply add 'display:block; float:none;' to the css class.
Optionally add 'overflow:hidden' if you don't like the exceding text starting a new line.